# Cardinality of a finite $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Can you help me to prove, that the cardinality of a finite $\sigma$-algebra is $2^n$ for a $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

My first idea was to look at an easy example, but even there i have a problem. I look at two subsets $A,B\subset\Omega$ and want these to be in the $\sigma$-Algebra. I get $\{\Omega, \varnothing, A, B, A^C, B^C, A\cup B, (A\cup B)^C, A\cup B^C, (A\cup B^C)^C, A^C\cup B, (A^C\cup B)^C, A^C\cup B^C, (A^C\cup B^C)^C\}$. So here at least two elements are missing or there are two elements too much. Can you please tell me where my mistake is and give me a hint how to prove the statement.

Comment: It might be easier to assume that $\{A,B\}$ is a partition of $\Omega$, so you have $\sigma(\{A,B\})\subseteq \mathcal{P}(\{A,B\})$ and $|\mathcal{P}(\{A,B\})|=2^{2}$. If $A,B\neq \emptyset$ were assumed too, then $\sigma(\{A,B\})= \mathcal{P}(\{A,B\})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing $(A\cap B)\cup (A\cup B)^c$ and its complement. Draw a Venn diagram and check this using brute force.